# Backend server and mongo database working with postman. But input datas don't post to database from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mern, internal-server-error, failed-to-connect

This is the Registration component in src folder

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const Registration = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        
    });
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/register/reg', formData);
            console.log('Registration successful');
            setError('');  // Reset error on success
            navigate('/MyCart');  // Redirect to login page
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Registration failed');
            console.error('Registration failed', error.response.data);
            setError(error.response.data.message);  // Set error message
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Registration</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name="username" value={formData.username} onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.target.value)} required />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    Email:
                    <input type="email" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.target.value)} required />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.target.value)} required />
                </label><br />
               
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
            {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Registration;
```

This is the users model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
    email:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    password: {type:String, required:true},
    isAdmin:{
        type: Boolean, default:false
    }
},
{timestamps: true}
    );

//module.exports = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

This the register.route.js under routes folder

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../database/models/users');  
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password, age } = req.body;

        // Hash the password
        const saltRounds = 10;
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

        // Create a new user with the hashed password
        const user = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword, age });

        // Save the user to the database
        await user.save();

        // Send a success response
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: {
                user
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        let errorMessage;

        if (err.code === 11000) {
            // Handle duplicate key error
            errorMessage = 'Email already exists';
        } else if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            // Handle Mongoose validation error
            errorMessage = Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message).join(', ');
        } else {
            // Generic error message
            errorMessage = err.message;
        }

        // Send a failed response
        res.status(500).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message: errorMessage
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the sever.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDB = require('./database/connect');
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const register = require("./routes/register.route");
const ProductsRoute = require("./routes/Product");




connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/reg", register);
app.use("/api/Product", ProductsRoute);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```

I have imported Registration component to App.js and wrap it with BrowserRouter

```
<Route path='/reg' element={<Registration/>}/>
```

I Got this console error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500(Internal server Error). I have tried to specify origin to the cors, as
app.use(cors({
origin:'http://localhost:5000/'
})); but it didn't work.

I got axios error and cors "Access-header-missing" errors before and make some changes to handle those errors.

I am beginner to MERN stack. So ,Please help me to make this work..

.

Comment: Too many updates needed, first use specific method in express like `app.post` instead `app.use` and use any one body parser it must be defined top of all routes. Try to log the error in `reg` route so you will have an idea about error origin. There is no mess with cors it is in localhost

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have made these changes. I removed `reg`  from route, registration component and app.js . Now I got the error Failed to load resource:  the server responded with a status of 404     @YuvarajM

Comment: edit your answer so i can see what you have done. Why did you removed that ? just log the error(catch block) inside the `reg` route

Comment: Obviously it gives 404 cause you removed it from routes

Comment: Check the code now, did you mean "Registration failed handleSubmit" ?

Comment: Just change the `/reg` in router file to `/` and `/register` in server js to `/reg`

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at handleSubmit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2236:59)

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: It means your server won't stated

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404,......again this error and Registration failed handleSubmit Registration.jsx:26 Registration failed  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /register/reg</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Change the url in Reg comp from  `/register/reg` to `/reg`

Comment: same error again . Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the frontend, you can add one more field, "age," and utilize a single onChange function to handle all input fields.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
 import {useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',age:''
    
});
const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const navigate = useNavigate();

//here's the modified code
function handleChange(e){
  const {name,value}=e.target;
  setFormData({...formData,[name]:value})
 }


const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  console.log('e: ', e,formData);
    e.preventDefault();
     try {
         await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/register/reg', formData);
         console.log('Registration successful');
      setError('');  // Reset error on success
        navigate('/MyCart');  // Redirect to login page
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Registration failed');
       // console.error('Registration failed', error.response.data);
       //setError(error.response.data.message);  // Set error message
    // }
};

return (
    <div>
        <h2>Registration</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="username" value={formData.username} onChange={handleChange} required />
            </label><br />
            <label>
                Email:
                <input type="email" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} required />
            </label><br />
            <label>
                Password:
                <input type="password" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={handleChange} required />
            </label><br />
           <label>
      Age:
      <input
        type="number"
        name="age"
        value={formData.age}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
      />
    </label>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
        {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
    </div>
);
}

export default App
```

And also modify the schema like this:

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    
    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
        email:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
        password: {type:String, required:true},
    //You can assign any datatype for age which you want 
    age:{type:String,required:true},
        isAdmin:{
            type: Boolean, default:false
        }
    },
    {timestamps: true}
        );
    
    //module.exports = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
    
    const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
    module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Comment: in server.js  use 

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
 then 
app.use("/reg", register);
app.use("/api/Product", ProductsRoute);
and in frontend match the routes  :http://localhost:5000/register/reg/